# ASP.NET CORE 2.2 authorization error redirect page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization

I wrote a Wep Application ASP NET CORE 2.2 in c# which uses the authorization. They work properly. When access is denied now the url is rewritten for example as follows:

```
https://ebbwebdev.azurewebsites.net/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2FTelemetries
```

and the page displayed is Error 404.

I'm using ASP.NET Core Identity.

How can I redirect access denied to a custom page?

Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: You are using [Authorize] on your classes?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core Identity or something else?

Comment: @GuilhermeMartin yes I'm using [Authorize].

Comment: @KirkLarkin : yes, I'm using ASP.NET CORE Identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply  do as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/YourCustomAccessDeniedPath";

    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Configuring `IdentityOptions` in `Startup` as below,

```cs
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(opt =>
{
    opt.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new PathString("/yourcustompage");
});
```

Comment: Seems not to find a definition for Cookies.