# Where do I define the url for an aspnetcore authorisation fail?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

So I've got aspnet identity razor pages in my asp.net core 3+ project.

When I click on login or register defaults it directs me to a url starting with `Identity` e.g.

```
https://localhost:12345/Identity/Account/Login
```

All of the navigations to the other pages, account management etc. work fine giving me this `Identity` prefix.

However, I added some userRoles and am using the `Authorize(Roles = "Admin")` attribute on my MVC `Admin` controller, so when I try to access the index page on this controller without signing in, it's trying to redirect me to login, with a returnURL in the querystring

**but**, the URL is missing the `Identity` prefix and sends me to:

```
https://localhost:12345/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fadmin
```

Where do I change this? I have no idea where this automatic redirection on authorisation failure is?!

---

**EDIT:** I'm thinking it may have something to do with the startup bit declaring endpoints:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
```

Not sure how I can alter that to make a default login path

Comment: Please check if you manually set `LoginPath` option with `/Account/Login` in Startup.ConfigureServices method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the URL is missing the `Identity` prefix and sends me to:

```
https://localhost:12345/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fadmin
```

If you set **LoginPath** with `"/Account/Login"` in `ConfigureServices` method of Startup.cs like below, which would cause above issue.

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    //options here

    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";

    //...
});
```

Comment: I haven't used that, I have no `.ConfigureApplicationCookie` but maybe there is a default in place? However I was able to use this to change my LoginPath to include the `Identity` area

Comment: You can try to explicitly set `options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";` and check if it can fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Refer these:
[ASP.NET - Redirect to Error Page if Roles Authorization Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447705/asp-net-redirect-to-error-page-if-roles-authorization-fails)
[ASP.NET CORE 2.2 authorization error redirect page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58149592/asp-net-core-2-2-authorization-error-redirect-page)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/YourCustomAccessDeniedPath";

    });

}
```

or

Configuring IdentityOptions in Startup as below,

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(opt =>
{
    opt.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new PathString("/yourcustompage");
});
```

Comment: Good info on how I can handle access denied, I could use that, however the second part with `IdentityOptions` didn't work. I'm not sure if aspnetcore 3.1 + has quite the same types.